# tkinter Combobox select next value instead of showing the whole list when pressing arrow keys

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I have several tkinter Comboboxes in my python application with the default tkinter behaviour that the 'up' arrow does nothing and the 'down' arrow shows the whole list of values, which can then be reaverserd with the arrow keys.
However, I would like to 'scroll' through the Comboboxes with the arrow keys without this list popping up (i.e. arrow down directly switches to the next element, arrow up directly switches to the previous element).

MWE of Combobox:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

app = tk.Tk()
combo = ttk.Combobox(app, values = [f"item {i}" for i in range(20)])
combo.grid()
```

(How) can I achieve this desired behaviour? Do I have to catch the key events or is there some setting that I'm missing?

Comment: Stepping through the elements of a combobox with up and down arrow is default. If I understand you right, you want to jump to the next box if you are at the last element of the previous box, right?

Comment: With the code above, when pressing the 'down' key, the list with all the items pops up and I can then use the arrow keys and enter to select the new item. But I want to skip this popup and directly switch to the next/previous item (with both 'up' and 'down'). I edited my question to be more clear what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that should work for both `Up` and `Down`

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


def select_next(event):
    selection = combo.current()  # get the current selection
    last = len(combo['values']) - 1  # index of last item
    key = event.keysym  # get the key that was pressed
    if key == 'Up':
        try:
            combo.current(selection - 1)  # set the combobox to the previous item
        except tk.TclError:  # end of list reached
            combo.current(last)  # wrap around to last item
    elif key == 'Down':
        try:  
            combo.current(selection + 1)  # set the combobox to the next item
        except tk.TclError:  # end of list reached
            combo.current(0)   # wrap around to first item
    return 'break'  # tell tk to dispose of this event and don't show the menu!


app = tk.Tk()
combo = ttk.Combobox(app, values = [f"item {i}" for i in range(20)])
combo.grid()
combo.current(0)  # select the first item by default
combo.bind('<Up>', select_next)  # up arrow
combo.bind('<Down>', select_next)  # down arrow
```

Comment: Looks good, thank you.
Since I don't want the wrapping, I changed the conditions to the following:
`if key == 'Up' and selection > 0:
  combo.current(selection - 1)
elif key == 'Down' and selection < last:
  combo.current(selection + 1)
return 'break'`

Comment: @Xoriun That works too! Glad to hear I could help out. If this worked for you, please mark this answer as "Accepted" so that others know this question has been answered.